# Java out of memory using fileoutstream

Tags: java, io, fileoutputstream

I,m trying to export some files from a system and save it in my drive, the problem is that some files are pretty big and I get the java out of memory error.

```
FileOutputStream fileoutstream = new FileOutputStream(filenameExtension);
fileoutstream.write(dataManagement.getContent(0).getData());
fileoutstream.flush();
fileoutstream.close();
```

Any recomendation that I can try, I add the flush but now diference, this will call the export method,  generate the file and saved. I,m using a cursos to run over the data that I,m exporting not an array, I try to add more memory but the files are too big.

Comment: Read and write the file in chunks.Try periodically flushing the output stream after some XXX amount of data is written .

Answer (score 2):

You are loading the whole file in memory before writing it.  On the contrary you should:

1. load only a chunk of data
2. write it
3. repeat the steps above until you have processed all data.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are really big, you may need to read/write them in chunks. If the files are big enough to fit in memory, then you can increase the size of the virtual machine memory.

i.e:

```
java -Xmx512M ...


FileInputStream fi = infile;
FileOutputStream fo = outfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
int n;
while((n = fi.read(buffer)) > 0)
    fo.write(b, 0, n);
```

Hope this helps to get the idea.

Comment: I try to add 1500m of memory but it faild, the file is like 300m, any example on how to read and write it in chunks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the spring batch framework to do the reading and writing the file in chunk size. 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/